# Postgresql notify and listen

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, notify, listen

Hi every one I'm doing a small program to listen and notify using POSTGRESQL and JAVA. I just want to get notification message, to be stored in a file or MySQL database. Can any one guide me where I can find documentation or sample code for this.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are using JDBC, you can use the PostgreSQL extensions of the standard. In particular, you need the `org.postgresql.PGNotification` class to receive notifications that you have to explicitly poll for. See the JDBC documentation [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/listennotify.html). There is a fully worked-out example in the docs.

Comment: I tried the code sample, but I cant understand it. Build successfully, didn't see how the program works?

Comment: "Can't understand it" is not a question that I can help you with. Give it some more thought and trial and post a new and specific question if you are still having trouble.